# remove double underscore from string

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, replace

I am using a series of REPLACE to remove special characters based on internal set of rules.

I do the multiple replace of some characters inside a stored procedure, first, and then I do a cross join to a UDF, passing the stripped value, along a regex that contains additional characters to be removed (not replaced)

If I do it that way, the following value gets correctly manipulated:

```
'O Sole Mio - Bass Clef Instrument
```

After the multiple REPLACE are applied, and the udf called, I end up with:

```
o_sole_mio_bass_clef_instrument
```

The problem I have is when I take all the REPLACE from the stored procedure, and put them in the UDF, when I run the code that way, then the same value is returned like:

```
o_sole_mio__bass_clef_instrument
```

---

### This works:

**Stored Procedure**

```
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @workTable TABLE
    (
        [wtID]      INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    ,   [sku]       VARCHAR(15)
    ,   [wtString]  VARCHAR(800)
    );

    INSERT  @workTable
    SELECT              
        1
    ,   REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(
                                REPLACE(
                                    REPLACE(
                                        REPLACE(
                                            LOWER('''O Sole Mio - Bass Clef Instrument')
                                        , CHAR(9), '')
                                    , '_', ' ')
                                , ' ', '_')
                            , '_-_', '_')
                        , '-', '_')
                    , '_&_', '_')
                , '=', '_')
            , '_/_', '_')
        , '/', '_')     

    SELECT      
        wt.sku
    ,   [wt].[wtString] AS 'ThisValueStillHasSomeCharactersTobeRemoved'
    ,   [MyResult] AS 'ThisValueIsTheExpectedResult'        
    FROM        
        @workTable [wt]     
    CROSS APPLY 
        [dbo].[RemoveValuesFromString]([wt].[wtString], '%[]~@#$%&*(),.,!¡^¿?:´''"/`+{},...,%')
    ORDER BY        
        [wt].[wtString]; 

END
```

**UDF:**

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[RemoveValuesFromString]
(
    @SearchVal NVARCHAR(MAX)
,   @CharsToRemove NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS TABLE

AS 

RETURN

WITH        [MyValues]      

AS 
( 
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING(@SearchVal, [N], 1) AS [MyChar]
    ,   [t].[N]
    FROM
        [cteTally] [t]
    WHERE
        [N] <= LEN(@SearchVal)
        AND CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@SearchVal, [N], 1), @CharsToRemove) = 0
)       

SELECT DISTINCT
    [MyResult] = STUFF((SELECT 
                            CAST([mv2].[MyChar] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CS_AS
                        FROM
                            [MyValues] [mv2]
                        ORDER BY
                            [mv2].[N]
                    FOR
                        XML PATH(''),   TYPE).[value]('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 0, '')
FROM
    [MyValues] [mv];
```

**Output**

```
sku ThisValueStillHasSomeCharactersTobeRemoved  ThisValueIsTheExpectedResult
1   'o_sole_mio_bass_clef_instrument            o_sole_mio_bass_clef_instrument
```

---

### This does not work:

**Stored Procedure**

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @workTable TABLE
    (
        [wtID]      INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    ,   [sku]       VARCHAR(15)
    ,   [wtString]  VARCHAR(800)
    );

    INSERT  @workTable
    SELECT              
        1
    ,   '''O Sole Mio - Bass Clef Instrument'

    SELECT      
        wt.sku
    ,   [wt].[wtString] AS 'ThisValueStillHasSomeCharactersTobeRemoved'
    ,   [MyResult] AS 'ThisValueIsTheExpectedResult'        
    FROM        
        @workTable [wt]     
    CROSS APPLY 
        [dbo].[RemoveValuesFromString]([wt].[wtString], '%[]~@#$%&*(),.,!¡^¿?:´''"/`+{},...,%')
    ORDER BY        
        [wt].[wtString];  

END
```

**UDF**

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[RemoveValuesFromString]
(
    @SearchVal NVARCHAR(MAX)
,   @CharsToRemove NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS TABLE       
AS      
RETURN      
WITH [MyValues]             
AS 
(   SELECT
        SUBSTRING(@SearchVal, [N], 1) AS [MyChar]
    ,   [t].[N]
    FROM
        [cteTally] [t]
    WHERE
        [N] <= LEN(@SearchVal)
        AND CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@SearchVal, [N], 1), @CharsToRemove) = 0
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    [MyResult] = STUFF((SELECT                                                                              
                            REPLACE(
                                REPLACE(
                                    REPLACE(
                                        REPLACE(
                                            REPLACE(
                                                REPLACE(
                                                    REPLACE(
                                                        REPLACE(
                                                            REPLACE(
                                                                LOWER(CAST([mv2].[MyChar] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1251_CS_AS)
                                                            , CHAR(9), '')
                                                        , '_', ' ')
                                                    , ' ', '_')
                                                , '_-_', '_')
                                            , '-', '_')
                                        , '_&_', '_')
                                    , '=', '_')
                                , '_/_', '_')
                            , '/', '_')                                                                                 
                        FROM
                            [MyValues] [mv2]
                        ORDER BY
                            [mv2].[N]
                    FOR
                        XML PATH(''),   TYPE).[value]('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 0, '')
FROM
    [MyValues] [mv];
```

**Output**

```
sku ThisValueStillHasSomeCharactersTobeRemoved  ThisValueIsTheExpectedResult
1   'O Sole Mio - Bass Clef Instrument          o_sole_mio___bass_clef_instrument
```

I hope I am asking the question correctly, I think I am just overlooking something really simple. I truly would appreciate some help.

Thank you much.

Comment: I ran your code as is and it worked correctly. http://rextester.com/RPQ83710

Comment: its giving desired output for me too

Comment: It works for me too. It's good to remember that the functions are always evaluated from the inside first.

Comment: I just finished updating my question, I included more t-sql hoping that will show potential places in which the error might be found. Thank you greatly.

Comment: Is there any chance that someone can help me figure out why I am having this issue? Thank you

Comment: it can be reproduced http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4ab64/1